# Discrete Math: Proof by Induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need to prove $3^{4n+2} + 5^{2n+1}$ is divisible by $14$ for $n=0, 1, 2\dots$

I did the base case $n=0$ and everything checked out. Then I assumed $n=k$ and want to prove $k+1$.

$3^{4k+6} + 5^{2k+3} =$

That's how far I got, what would I do next? Separate powers?

Comment: You forgot to set $n=k+1$ in the second sumand, i.e. you should get

$$3^{4k + 6} + 5^{2k+3}$$

Comment: @5xum OP already corrected that typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A+B$ is a multiple of 14, then the next sum is $81A+25B$.  Why would that be a multiple of 14?

Answer (score 0):

Without induction:

$$3^{4n+2}+5^{2n+1}=9^{2n+1}+5^{2n+1}=14\left(9^{2n}-9^{2n-1}5\pm\cdots+5^{2n}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

For $n=k+1$ we have
\begin{align}
3^{4k+6}+5^{2(k+1)+1}&=3^4\cdot 3^{4k+2}+5^2\cdot5^{2k+1}\\
&=3^4\cdot 3^{4k+2}+\color{red}{3^4\cdot5^{2k+1}}+5^2\cdot5^{2k+1}-\color{red}{3^4\cdot5^{2k+1}}\\
&=3^4\cdot(3^{4k+2}+5^{2k+1})+5^{2k+1}\cdot(25-81)\\
&=3^4\cdot(3^{4k+2}+5^{2k+1})-5^{2k+1}\cdot 14\cdot 4\\
\end{align}
Since $3^{4k+2}+5^{2k+1}$ is supposed to be a multiple of $14$ you get $3^{4k+6}+5^{2(k+1)+1}$ also is divisble by $14$.